# How to get predict label from a CNN text classification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, text-classification

I am new to CNN text classification. I want to classify text into one of two labels.

0 = tidak mengidap

1 = mengidap

My model only returns 0, no matter what sequence.

```
lstm_out = 150

model = Sequential()
model.add(embedding_layer)
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=5, activation='relu', padding='causal'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.7))
model.add(LSTM(units=lstm_out))
model.add(Dropout(0.7))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])


X_sample = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df['stemmed'])
X_sample = pad_sequences(X_sample, maxlen=maxlentweet)
y_sample = model.predict(X_sample).flatten().tolist()
result = np.argmax(y_sample)

print(result)
```

Comment: Because your final layer is one dimension (`Dense(1)`), of course `np.argmax(y_sample)` always return 0. Try change your final layer to `model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))`.

Comment: it works with sparse_categorical_crossentropy